# Which is best flow of Login in Roku?

Tags: roku, brightscript

I Perform a simple Login in a Roku and store data into Registry.

**case 1**

Below scenario, I maintain Focus with textboxes and Button. and Click ok to Email EditBox to open a dialog box and save to roRegistrySection. and if the user enters correct Data then navigate to Another View.

[image]

**case 2**

In this case, I tried to Directly open a dialog box and ok press to another dialog box. Both Email and Password are Correct then navigate to another view.

[image]

Here I implement the two way But not sure Which way is Best in ROKU. Anyone know about the Login Flow in ROKU.

Comment: by the way you have "sing" instead of "sign" !

Answer (score 2):

I would prefer the first option since it's more clear to me as a user what I'm doing. Honestly this question is more about preference than anything else. There is no clear answer.